# How to use insertion operator with a shared_ptr pointer of an ifstream object?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, ifstream

I am trying to read from a file using a shared_ptr pointer. I don't know how I can use insertion operator with it. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path="";    
    map<string, int> container;
    cout<<"Please Enter Your Files Path: ";
    getline(cin,path);

    shared_ptr<ifstream> file = make_shared<ifstream>();
    file->open(path,ifstream::in);
    string s="";
    while (file->good())
    {
        file>>s;
        container[s]++;
        s.clear();
    }

    cout <<"\nDone..."<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

simply doing:

```
file>>s;
```

doesn't work.

How can I get the current value that file is pointing (I don't want to get the whole line, I just need to get the words and number of their occurrences this way).

By the way, I used shared_ptr to avoid closing the file myself, does making a pointer of this type, shared_ptr (smart) will it suffice not to write the `file->close()` myself ? or they are irrelevant?

Comment: Why use `share_ptr<ifstream>` over `ifstream file`?

Comment: You do know that via RAII the file closes itself as it leaves scope right?

Comment: yes , but i thought it is a good idea to pass the file to multiple functions and this way i avoid declaring multiple ifstream objects on different methods.! i dont know if its reasonable or not! if it is a silly decision then i remove it .

Comment: @Hossein - the standard way of passing streams around to other functions/classes is to pass by a reference to an `istream` object - so no copying required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the dereference `operator *`:

```
(*file) >> s;
```

But looking at the code, I see no reason whatsoever to use a smart pointer. You could just use an `ifstream` object.

```
std::ifstream file(path); // opens file in input mode
```

Comment: i thought it is a good idea to pass the file to multiple functions and this way i avoid declaring multiple ifstream objects on different methods.! i dont know if its reasonable or not! if it is a silly decision then i remove it

Comment: @Hossein You could pass references to `file` to your functions.

Comment: wont that delete my object when the function ends and we return back to main?

Comment: @Hossein no, it won't! Read up on passing by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want it to be a pointer? It's that that is causing you pain.

```
ifstream file;
file.open( ...
...
file>>s;
```

Streams are intended to be treated as value (rather than pointer types). The file will be closed when the destructor is called on the `ifstream`.

If you need to pass the stream object round other parts of your code, you simply use references (to the base class):

```
void other_fn( istream & f )
{
    string something;
    f>>something;
}

ifstream file;
other_fn( file );
```

Because the `f` parameter is a reference, it doesn't attempt to close the stream/file when it goes out of scope - that still happens in the scope that defines the original `ifstream` object.